# crash while processing a message received from a jms producer

Tags: jms, ejb-3.1

what happen if a jms mdb consumer is crash while processing a message received from a jms producer ? will it be able to consume the message again when recover ?
is it depend on consumer acknowledge mode ? or aon transactional definition on the mdb ? or other things ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of things actually. Different JMS implementations have different behaviors.

The key is that **persistent** messages should not be lost. So they should be possible to re-run. So an uncaught exception in a MDB will roll back a persistent message. Please note that this may cause something called "poison message". Imagine a very specific message that causes a NullPointerException in the MDB.

That message will rollback to queue, then be processed again, then rollback etc. All very quickly. In many setups that will flood the logs, consume a lot of resources and stop working messages to pass by. To cope with that, most/all JMS implementations has a concept dead-letter-queue (or backout queue) that corrupt messages will go to after a certain number of retries, for manual inspection. Exactly how that works and is configured is implementation specific.

A common "best practice" working with MDBs is to only do a rollback on transient errors. I.e. if the database is unreachable, or a HTTP resource is unavailable - then a retry makes sense. If you hit some other error, such as NullPointerException or figure out you can't parse the incoming message - it's better to catch the exception and close the processing as nicely as possible (with good loggning, error messages and so forth). That's because it's likely a bug in either sender or receiver side.

Comment: ok , but lets say my mdb already read the message and before saving it to DB , the jvm crash. Now , when my application start again , will it receive that message again from the queue ?

Comment: Yes - at least if the message was persistent. Keep in mind some JMS implementations will kick the message out to a dead letter queue at some point. You have to read the docs of the product you're working with to understand how that works.

Comment: Why the message has to be persistent? I am saying that my jvm had crashed not the jms broker

Comment: As you ask about JMS in general and not about a specific product, it's hard to give a definite answer. You "may" have that  message redelivered. By defining a message as "non persistent", you define it as non essential and can live without it. So your question is always true for persistent messages and maybe true for non persistent (depending on your product etc)

Comment: Thank you.my question is about IBM MQ implementation.